# How to read ".38" as in ".38 gun"?

Tags: vocabulary

Could it be read like this: Thirty-eight caliber gun?

Could I use it in the following example: The inspector took his thirty-eight caliber gun?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is read as ***thirty-eight caliber***, but is usually written as ***.38*** or ***38 caliber***.